# Layout issues in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

In Opera my website logo appears out of place. I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out how to fix this. It works just fine in Firefox and Chromium. The ID for the logo is simply 'Logo'.

The site it located at http://next.icartrading.com/

If this isn't the best place to post this problem, tell me where else. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand, why the other browsers are rendering it the way you want. If you ask me I would think that Opera is doing the right thing here.

Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you but the problem definitely is the width (840px) of the `HeaderContent` which is too small to hold both elements `MenuWrapper` and `Logo` (combined width 914px). Is it not possible for you to increase the `HeaderContent`'s width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you so rudely voted down my previous reply, this one will come with the exact code you need to change, plus an online demo showing you what it should look like.

To your CSS, add this:

```
#HeaderContent
{
  position: relative;
}
#Logo
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -55px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

(replacing any existing declarations you may have had for those values.)

The demonstration is here:

http://aesoft.org/zarel/rq/crown.html

If your version does not look like this, it is because of *your* mistakes, not mine, and I would appreciate asking another question instead of voting me down.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to downvote anything.

Comment: Ah, well, then, two other people voted down my reply for seemingly no reason. :(